# Why I can't enable webgpu in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, compute-shader

I'm trying to use `webgpu` in my web app. I found [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/webgpu/) guide of how to use WebGL compute feature. I enabled `#enable-webgpu-developer-features` flag and even run Google Chrome with `--enable-unsafe-webgpu` option. But still receive `null` on calling `canvas.getContext('webgpu')` and `navigator.gpu` is `undefined`. When I'm trying to see [these demos](https://austin-eng.com/webgpu-samples/samples/helloTriangle), I observe `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'requestDevice')`

Are there some hardware requirements, or specific drivers, or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem with Chrome 106, but the demos you link work for me when I use [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/) instead of Chrome. I had to restart the browser after enabling the flag to get most demos to work, but that one in particular worked without it. I suspect it has to do with the Origin Trial of WebGPU.

Comment: And Origin Trial WebGPU doesn't require "unsafe webgpu" flag?

Comment: I think it's not required if the site is part of the origin trial. The link you posted worked for me without enabling the flag, but other demos I found online only worked after I set the flag and restarted.

Comment: I've tried with Chrome Canary and it works only with flag for me=) Anyway, any ideas why it doesn't work with simple Google Chrome?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the origin trial was paused for two weeks starting two weeks ago today (“Caution
The origin trial is expected to pause for 2 weeks starting in Chrome 106 (Sep 27, 2022).” from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/web-platform/webgpu/)), so maybe things will change after today?

I would have thought the flag was independent of the origin trial, though, so I'm confused about this as well.